# MacBook Pro doesn’t turn on without charger

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

MacBook Pro 2012 non retina model 13.3 inch.

I am trying to turn on MacBook with a replacement battery 11.1 V, 6000 mAh, 66.6 W I installed myself.

The original battery was 10.95 V, 63.5 W.

The MacBook turns on & replacement battery charges when the charger is connected, but when charger is disconnected the MacBook turns off. That is I cannot turn on MacBook without the power adapter with the new replacement battery.

Original battery info 
[image: originalBatteryInfo]

New Replacement battery info
[image]

Comment: @dan I replaced the battery, if you are asking about manufacturer it’s unknown.

Comment: The replacement battery you purchased is faulty/defective.  Send it back.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your new battery, from the screenshot above, is only supplying 7.3V, which is presumably too low to power the motherboard sufficiently on its own, it should be closer to 12V.

So your battery might be rated 11.1V but it appears to be faulty, although it is not self-reporting as such, maybe because the mAh rating and cycle count is still ok.

Comment: Is it possible to still use MacBook with faulty battery with AC power adapter plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

If the replacement wasn't done by Apple, this is one of the rare case where a
reset of the SMC might be useful.

If you already performed an SMC reset after your battery replacement,
then your battery is faulty.

Else [reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)
and check again the voltage provided by your battery.

If it is still below 12000 mV, then it is faulty.
Otherwise you witnessed one of the rare case where an SMC reset is useful.

Comment: Is it ok to use the MacBook with combination of 7v battery and AC adapter?